# SQL Server on Azure connected to REST API Express.js/Node.js [TypeError: req.sql is not a function]

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, azure, express

Hi im having an issue connecting to Azure SQL Server with express4-tedious. I am trying to make an app in react-native with Node/Express server (REST API) but after express4-tedios setup in express this error came up:
req.sql is not a function

TypeError: req.sql is not a function

this is my app.js on server Folder

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cors = require("cors");
var tediousExpress = require('express4-tedious');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var testAPIRouter = require("./routes/testAPI");

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use("/testAPI", testAPIRouter);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.sql = tediousExpress(req, 
    {
    "server"  : "something.database.windows.net",
    "userName": "something",
    "password": "something",
    "options": { "encrypt": true, "database": "something" }
    }
    );
  next();
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

and this is my testAPI.js where I am running req.sql() function

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {

  req.sql("select * from Persons for json path")
      .into(res);

});

module.exports = router;
```

I really appreciate anybody's help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you are defining the **middleware** after the routes. You must first define this middleware. And the, call the routes to be defined.

E.g:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.sql = tediousExpress(req, 
    {
    "server"  : "something.database.windows.net",
    "userName": "something",
    "password": "something",
    "options": { "encrypt": true, "database": "something" }
    }
    );
  next();
});

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use("/testAPI", testAPIRouter);
```

Comment: OK, thank you very much, it works for no errors. The problem there is that my localhost on testAPI is blank and no table from my sql server is swown.
Don't you know why is that?